# Открыть новое окно браузера с картинкой

Tags: javascript

Есть картинка

```
<img src="photo/ar1.jpg" href="#" alt="Изображения нет" title="Посмотреть большое фото" onclick="openRis(0)">
```

По нажатию на картинку должна вывестись эта же картинка, но в новом окне.
По каким форумам только не лазил, не помогает ничего. Сделать надо с помощью JS!!!
пробовал так

```
var w = window.open("about:blank","help", "width=300", "height=200");
w.document.open();
w.document.body.innerHTML("<img src='photo/ar1.jpg'>");
```

и так

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = "photo/ar1.j";
var width = image.width;
var height = image.height;
window.open(src,"Image","width=" + width + ",height=" + height);
```

и даже как-то так

```
var newWin=window.open("about:blank","hello","height=500,width=500");
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.className = "alert";

var newimg = document.createElement("img");
newimg.setAttribute("src","photo/ar1.jpg");
document.getElementById("alert").appendChild(newimg);
```

Уже веревку с мылом ищу, помогите, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
const c = document.getElementById("my-image"); // берем картинку по id
const d = c.src; // берем ее src
const w = window.open('about:blank','new image'); // открываем окно
w.document.write("<img src='" + d + "' alt='from old image' />"); //  вставляем картинку
```

P.S. Прототип: https://jsfiddle.net/bauop5q8/2/

Answer (score 1):

**Пример на [Codepen](https://codepen.io/meine89/full/pGZbRm)**

```js
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll("img");

for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
  imgs[i].addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    let src = e.currentTarget.src;
    window.open("about:black", "image").document.write("<img src='" + src + "' alt='something' />");
  });
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="1">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/310" alt="2">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/320" alt="3">
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно обернуть картинки в тег `a` и воспользоваться атрибутом `target="_blank"`.

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" target="_blank">
  <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" href="#" alt="Изображения нет" title="Посмотреть большое фото">
</a>
```

P.S. Сниппет не работает, смотрите в [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/a7bv6hey/).